# Need input with passing commands in Kubernetes containers

Tags: shell, kubernetes, command, containers, kubernetes-container

What is the difference in below three declarations for passing command/arguments:

1. containers:
   name: busybox
   image: busybox
   args:
   -sleep
   -"1000"
2. containers:
   name: busybox
   image: busybox
   command: ["/bin/sh", "-c", "sleep 1000"]
3. containers:
   name: busybox
   image: busybox
   args:
   -sleep
   -"1000"

A. Would these produce same result?
B. What is the preference or usage for each?

Answer (score 1):

The YAML list definition are only a matter of taste, it's just a YAML syntax. This two examples are equivalent:

```
listOne:
- item1
- item2
listTwo: ['item1', 'item2']
```

And this syntax works for both **args** and **command**. Beside that **args** and **command** are slight different, as the documentation says:

- If you do not supply command or args for a Container, the defaults
  defined in the Docker image are used
- If you supply a command but no args for a Container, only the supplied command is used. The default EntryPoint and the default Cmd defined in the Docker image are ignored.
- If you supply only args for a Container, the default Entrypoint defined in the Docker image is run with the args that you supplied.
- If you supply a command and args, the default Entrypoint and the default Cmd defined in the Docker image are ignored. Your command is run with your args.

Imagine a container like **mysql**, if you look it's Dockerfile you'll notice this:

```
ENTRYPOINT ["docker-entrypoint.sh"]
CMD ["mysqld"]
```

The **entrypoint** call a script that prepare everything the database needs, when finish, this script calls `exec "$@"` and the shell variable `$@` are everything defined in **cmd**.

So, on Kubernetes, if you want to pass arguments to **mysqld** you do something like:

```yaml
image: mysql
args:
- mysqld
- --skip-grant-tables
# or args: ["mysqld", "--skip-grant-tables"]
```

This still executes the **entrypoint** but now, the value of `$@` is `mysqld --skip-grant-tables`.